# Python Read File, Look up a String and Remove Characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of numbers (NDC - drug numbers) that have a `-` in them. I am trying to read the file, remove the `-` and write the numbers to a new file. Any help with this would be appreciated. Using Py 2.7

```
1. 68817-0134-50
2. 68817-0134-50
3. 68817-0134-50
```

The issue is that the hyphen is not always in the same position.

```
1. 8290-033010
```

It changes and can be in any position

```
with open('c:\NDCHypen.txt', 'r') as infile,
     open('c:\NDCOnly.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    replace("-", "")
```

Comment: On what do you `replace`?  You must add a loop over the `infile`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
with open(r'c:\NDCHypen.txt', 'r') as infile, \
     open(r'c:\NDCOnly.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = data.replace("-", "")
    outfile.write(data)
```

To prevent the conversion of line endings (e.g. between `'\r\n'` and `\n'`), open both files in binary mode: pass `'rb'` or `'wb'` as the 2nd arg of *open*.

Comment: is there any way to rewrite the initial file that is opened? for example, how do you remove text or a row from `'c:\NDCHyphen.txt'`??

Comment: @BugWhisperer: Yes, there are multiple options, some of them are atomic. Please ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it easily with a shell script which would be must faster than a python implementation. Unless you have something more with the script, you should go with the shell script version.

However, with Python it would be:

```
with open('c:\NDCHypen.txt', 'r') as infile, open('c:\NDCOnly.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    temp = infile.read().replace("-", "")
    outfile.write(temp)
```

Comment: Not sure who and why the negative; but this works like a charm too. Thank you!

Comment: I think it's hard to predict (and it's also system-dependent) whether the shell script or Python implementation is faster. For large files both of them would be I/O-bound, so the wall time difference should be negligible. The Python implementation uses more memory (it keeps 2 copies of the input in memory), which is wasteful for large files.