# Removing a specific character from a text file

Tags: python, file

I'm new to Python and coding generally, and I was doing a tiny project and I'm facing a problem:

```
44, 1, 6
23, 2, 7
49, 2, 3
53, 2, 1
68, 1, 6
71, 2, 7
```

I just need to remove the 3rd and the 6th character from each line, or more specifically the "," characters from the whole file.

and i need to do it using my python code

```
for line in my_file:
       ??????????????
```

Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: This is not a code-writing service, and there are probably thousands of questions on how to modify text files in Python already on StackOverflow...

Comment: `[''.join(c for c in line if c != '.') for line in my_file]`

Comment: @not_a_robot or, you could just use `.replace`...

Comment: i'm working on a book cipher decoder, but i just needed that particular step because i wrote the whole thing and i got stuck with it, and i couldn't find it on stackoverflow for python

Comment: Right, well, this is *still* not an on-topic question. Again, **this is not a code-writing service**. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the character

```
with open(r'c:\input.txt', 'r') as infile,
     open(r'c:\output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = data.replace(",", "")
    outfile.write(data)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201575/python-read-file-look-up-a-string-and-remove-characters)

Comment: I wish instead of down voting and editing my answer you could have given solution

Comment: I didn't downvote... others did that. I also rolled back the edit when I realised I was wrong

Comment: data = data.replace(",", "")

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you answered a question that does not meet the guidlines.

Comment: question guidelines or answer? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Question guidelines.