# Why my file end up blank when I try to remove characters?

Tags: python, file-writing

I followed this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201575/python-read-file-look-up-a-string-and-remove-characters) because I want to remove the `<br />` that are in my output text file.

So my code is the following one :

```py
def file_cleaner(video_id):
    with open('comments_'+video_id+'.txt', 'r') as infile, open('comments_'+video_id+'.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        temp = infile.read().replace("<br />", "")
        outfile.write(temp)
```

If I remove this function call my file has content, but after I call this function my file is empty. Where did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Opening a file in `w` mode empties it first.

Comment: You cannot `open()` the same file twice.  Also `'w'` truncates the file when it opens it.

Comment: so what should I change ?

Comment: @J.erome Try opening a _different_ file as `outfile`.  Otherwise, you'll have to open the file _once_ for both reading _and_ writing `'r+'`.  Read the file data, change it, then write the new data back (making sure to "rewind" the file first).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python I guess it's my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening a file in `w` mode truncates the file first. So there's nothing to read from the file.

Read the file first, then open it for writing.

```
def file_cleaner(video_id):
    with open('comments_'+video_id+'.txt', 'r') as infile:
        temp = infile.read().replace("<br />", "")
    with open('comments_'+video_id+'.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(temp)
```

Comment: ...with the caveat that the file can end up corrupt if the program exits partway through the `outfile.write()` operation, hence why there are a lot of existing Q&A entries about how to _atomically_ update a file's contents in Python.